# PRACTICE cmm script how to v.v a new variable in an old window

Tags: jtag, trace32, lauterbach

This opens a window of variable `a`:

```
v.v a
```

View variable `b` in the same window.  How to do tihs?

```
v.v b
```

I know this can put them in the same window, but I want to view `b` at a later time

```
v.v a b
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it myself.

`Var.AddWatch var`

will do the job.

Comment: Be careful - I'm not quite sure whether `Var.View` and `Var.Watch` do the same thing. I would expect `Var.AddWatch` to do the same thing as `Var.Watch`, reusing the preexisting window for another watch expression.